# Edit body of email that triggers ItemSend event

Tags: vba, outlook

A footer is appended to every email I send. That's fine, until we get a dozen instances of the same footer at the end of an email. So I've been running the following code

```vb
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
      
    Dim currMail As MailItem
    Dim msgStr As String
    Dim endStr As String
    Dim endStrStart As Long
      
    On Error GoTo Error_CalItem
    Set currMail = ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
    endStr = "CONFIDENTIALITY NOTICE: This e-mail message"
      
    msgStr = currMail.HTMLBody
    endStrStart = InStr(msgStr, endStr)
      
    If endStrStart > 0 Then
        currMail.HTMLBody = Left(msgStr, endStrStart - 1)
    End If
Error_CalItem:
    'Nothing
End Sub
```

Since we switched to Office 365 this no longer works.

The issue is ActiveInspector is Nothing. Confirmed via:

```
Set oInspector = Application.ActiveInspector
If oInspector Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "No active inspector"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the instance passed as an argument instead:

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

    Dim currMail As MailItem
    Dim msgStr As String
    Dim endStr As String
    Dim endStrStart As Long

    On Error GoTo Error_CalItem

    ' check the item type first
    If TypeOf Item Is MailItem Then
        Set currMail = Item
        endStr = "CONFIDENTIALITY NOTICE: This e-mail message"

        msgStr = currMail.HTMLBody
        endStrStart = InStr(msgStr, endStr)

        If endStrStart > 0 Then
            currMail.HTMLBody = Left(msgStr, endStrStart - 1)
        End If
     End If 
Error_CalItem:
    'Nothing
End Sub
```